# ZMQ prevent sending "timedout" messages

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I wonder how can I "abort" a message after it has not been sent for sometime.

The scenario is simple:
1) Client connects to server
2) The server goes down
3) client send a message, there's no issue here as Zmq queues the message locally (so the "send" operation is successful) 
4) Assume I've set RCVTIMEO I get the timeout
5) After I got the timeout I no longer wish to send the message, but once the server goes up again Zmq will transmit the message. How can I prevent it?

The reason I want to prevent this is because once I got the timeout I responded back to my customer with failure message (e.g "the request could not be processed due to timeout"), and it would be a real issue if eventually his request would get transmitted and processed...

Hope my question is clear... Thx!

Comment: The only way I know of to cancel/abort a message is to close the entire socket. The main issue with this is that if there are other messages in the socket's send queue that you do want to go out, they will be cancelled/aborted as well.

Comment: Yeah, I read about the option of closing the socket, hoped there was a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** ) set **`aClientSOCKET`** instance **`ZMQ_LINGER`** parameter not to spend any time to re-send any en-queued messages during the forthcoming socket dismantling operations ( which is fairly in-line with the modern high-performance / low-latency distributed messaging systems design -- things go wrong, quite often go wrong, so work with this as a matter of fact rather than lose time fighting against un-avoidable ... )

and

**Step 2** ) force the **`.close()`** to discard the socket

and

**Step 3** ) if needed, re-instate another socket / communication means or use another a-priori-prepared means **( alike the binary-star fault-resilient shading )** to resolve the intended application processing after the situation the { "primary" | "observed" }-connection-peer handshaking time-out-ed.